# Read file comments from a zip file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, zip, rubyzip

I am doing [Python challenge](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/) in Ruby. I need to read the file contents and comments from a Zip file. The content is no problem with the [RubyZip](http://rubyzip.sourceforge.net/) gem but I am unable to get the comments out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll actually want the comments from each of the files, which I had a much harder time finding [documentation on](http://rubyzip.sourceforge.net/classes/Zip/ZipEntry.html).  Here's an example of how to get the comment from a file.

```
require 'zip/zip'

Zip::ZipFile.open("6.zip") do |zipfile|
  p zipfile.get_entry("90052.txt").comment
end
```

Comment: What I implemented was:
    myzip = Zip::ZipFile.open("channel.zip")
    comment += myzip.find_entry("#{name}.txt").comment

Answer (score 7):

According to the documentation an instance of the [RubyZip ZipFile](http://rubyzip.sourceforge.net/classes/Zip/ZipFile.html) class has a `comment` attribute which returns the zip file's comment, if it has one.

e.g.

```
require 'zip/zip'

Zip::ZipFile.open('zip_with_comment.zip') do |zipfile|
  puts zipfile.comment
end
```